# 3 letters month and 2 digits year format in R

Tags: r, date, format

I am trying to convert the following format to date:

```
as.Date('Mar.17', format = '%b.%y')
```

but it returns NA.

What am I missing?

**Update,** I am expecting to get March 2017, not 2018

Comment: It's not a date unless it has a month, day, and year.

Comment: Could try: `as.Date(paste0('Mar.17',1), format = '%b.%y%d')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be:

```
as.Date('Mar.17', format = '%b.%d')
```

Comment: ... if it's the current year.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted it to convert to March 1, 2017

Comment: you cannot expect R to understand that you want March 1st; so how about lubridate::dmy(paste(1, 'Mar.17') (I prefere lubridate functions for handing date variables)

Answer (score 1):

`as.yearmon` from `zoo` package will do the trick and provide `date(Mar 2017)` as expected by OP.

```
library(zoo)

as.yearmon("Mar.17", "%b.%y")
#[1] "Mar 2017"
```

Another option to convert it to `1 March 2017`

```
as.Date(as.yearmon("Mar.17", "%b.%y"), frac = 0)
#[1] "2017-03-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `17` part is the year, you could use `sub` to add in a day number to make it an actual date.

```
as.Date(sub("\\.", "01", "Mar.17"), "%b%d%y")
# [1] "2017-03-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the point for %b month format, at least in my computer

```
as.Date(paste0( "01",'mar.2017'), format = '%d%b%Y')
```

`"2017-03-01"`